# Cmd: use batch file to process %date% variable failed

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I wish to use batch command to parse %date% variable, to get year/month/date, like this:

```
>echo %date
Tue 08/18/2015
```

I wish to parse %a=2015, %b=08, %c=18, so I have the .bat like below:

```
@echo off
rem Get current date and calculate DayOfWeek
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set /A mm=%%a, dd=%%b, yy=%%c
)
```

But it failed to execute, saying that:

```
Missing operator.
```

How to fix my .bat file? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `"delims=/"`, the first token in `"Tue 08/18/2015"` results to `Tue 08`. Use

```
@echo off
rem Get current date and calculate DayOfWeek
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do (
    set /A "_mm=1%%a %% 100"
    set /A "_dd=1%%b %% 100"
    set /A _yy=%%c
)
set _
```

Output:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\32062701.bat
_dd=18
_mm=8
_yy=2015
```

The `set /A "mm=1%%a %% 100"` trick prevents from `Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021)` error. Read *entire* `set /?` or http://ss64.com/nt/set.html for explanation on decimal (`17`) vs. hexadecimal (`0x11`) vs. octal (`021`) denotation of the same number.

> The octal notation can be confusing - all numeric values that start
>   with zeros are treated as octal but `08` and `09` are not valid octal
>   digits. For example, `SET /a _month=07` will return the value `7`, but `SET /a _month=09` will return an error.

`1%%a` means *concatecation* of strings `1` and (evaluated) `%%a`: results to `108` if `%%a` evaluates to `08`. `%%` is batch notation of [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator. Hence, `1%%a %% 100` means the remainder after (integer) division of `108` by `100`, i.e. `8`.

To get your script locale independent, extract values from WMIC output rather:

```
wmic os get LocalDateTime | find "."
```

or try

```
wmic path Win32_LocalTime get /value
```

Comment: Thanks, I just don't quite catch the "set" trick. What does 1%%a mean? and what doest %% 100 mean? And what is the space inside "1%%a %% 100" actually mean?

Comment: @ImmanuelKant - `1%%a` means take the value of %%a and stick a 1 in front of it. `%%` is the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) operator. The spaces are unnecessary and merely personal preference, probably for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the `%date%` variable is unreliable because the format changes depending on the locale/regional/user settings on the machine.

This is one way to get a reliable date string.

```
@echo off

rem The four lines below will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec MS variables in XP Pro and higher.

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%" & set "MS=%dt:~15,3%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%" & set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%-%MS%"

echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the DayOfWeek in your computer, you have two simple solutions. The first one is to get it directly from the first word of your %date% variable "Tue 08/18/2015" **`:)`**:

```
for /F %%a in ("%date%") do set dow=%%a
```

But if you want to perform the numeric calculation, you may use the method to convert a date into the Julian Day Number shown at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032810/bat-file-to-change-a-file-name-to-1-day-less-than-current-date/21037600#21037600):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Modify next line accordingly to your locale format (this one use "Dow MM/DD/YYYY")
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%") do set /A mm=1%%a-100, dd=1%%b-100, yyyy=%%c

rem Convert the Date to Julian Day Number, and get its Day Of Week (0=Sunday, ..., 6=Saturday)
set /A a=(mm-14)/12, jdn=(1461*(yyyy+4800+a))/4+(367*(mm-2-12*a))/12-(3*((yyyy+4900+a)/100))/4+dd-32075, dow=(jdn+1)%%7

rem Show the result
echo Day of week: %dow%
```

The `set` command use the trick explained in other answers in order to  correctly get numbers greater than 07 that start with zero. For example, if the mont is `08`, then `set /A mm=1%%a-100` is `set /A mm=108-100`, that gives 8.

However, if you want to use this method on different computers, that may have different locale date formats, then you must use the method suggested by foxidrive.